# How to copy objects from one S3 bucket to another

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have found a solution for syncing S3 buckets data over link [Copy objects between S3 buckets](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/move-objects-s3-bucket/)

```
aws s3 sync s3://DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET-SOURCE s3://DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET-TARGET
```

But I want to copy specific files from the production S3 bucket to the staging s3 bucket via the file paths that are stored in the production database. Any suggestion of how I can achieve that using Laravel `aws-sdk-php`, `lambda function`, or `aws-cli`?

Comment: I'm not sure how where the paths come from changes what you need to do? Can you show us any code you've tried?

Comment: Paths are stored in this format `/downloads/5/1cb5c6dc-349f-4653-b198-870fbbbb45ac.zip` What I want is to copy zip files like this from one bucket to other.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html#copyobject all the parameters are documented however I'll point out that the path you shared does not include the S3 bucket so you'd have to provide those yourself